# How to Implement Python turtle Graphics-"Draw One Side Of A Square"?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

[Turle Graphics Questions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6v1F.png)

I go through this code
I am thinking that the answer is to draw a square irrespective of the color
Tell me the correct explanation
and in turtle graphics when you add acolor.color() to get the color to the turtle line
but the answer is "Draw one side of a square"

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Instead, post the code as text and provide a link to its source if it's publicly available. This will help others to easily reproduce your problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood: You think the answer is A, but the correct one is C.
Simply analyze the question. It says "each iteration through the loop".

An iteration through a for-loop is just executing the code in that for-loop **once**.

If I understrood Your question right, I guess You thought about what happens when the code fully executes (the foor-loop code repeats 4 times) instead of what happens when it goes 1 time as stated in the question "each iteration through the loop".

With "each iteration through the loop" the below code happens:

```
alex.forward(50)
alex.left(90)
```

And this code draws "one side of a square". So the correct answer is C.

If I understood correctly, You ask what would happen if we added `aColor.color()` to the loop.
The variable `aColor` is the current 'thing' from the list that's 'iterated through' at the moment.
It means that with each iteration of the for-loop `aColor` will be `"yellow"`, then `"red"`, then `"green"`, and lastly `"blue"`.

It means that `aColor` is a string.

Strings do not have a `.color()` function, so if we added `aColor.color()` into the for-loop an `AttributeError` would be raised as shown in https://i.imgur.com/5WIkzrf.png

If You meant what would happen if we added `turtle.color(aColor)` at the beginning of the for-loop's code like this:

```
import turtle
for aColor in ["red","green","blue","yellow"]:
    turtle.color(aColor)
    turtle.forward(50)
    turtle.left(90)
```

This image would be drawn by the turtle:
https://i.imgur.com/Az9YCiR.png.

The question You had trouble with was just tricky.

PS: In my opinion: Python is free to install and pretty easy to set-up.
I recommend downloading python along with some quality python code editor like PyCharm Community if You want to learn it. You could have pretty easily answered this question Yourself if You just ran the code instead of wondering what would happen.

Comment: I missed the small thing "each iteration"-Thank you So Much